# C# MySql JS Воспроизведение аудио mp3 файла с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, binary, blob

Связка языков C# и JS. Развернута база MySql, есть таблица, в которой одна из колонок хранит двоичные данные. Реализована интеграция протокола C# NFS, где я беру данные с удаленного сервера и записываю в ту саму таблицу *.mp3 файл в виде, соответственно, двоичных данных. Получаю с БД массив байт.
Следующая задача состоит в том, чтобы воспроизводить, скаченный ранее *.mp3 файл, сейчас хранящийся в БД в виде двоичных данных на локальном сервере, на клиенте, с помощью JS.

Comment: Выплюнь его в хттп с хидером и играй

Comment: [тыц](https://www.clicktorelease.com/blog/loading-sounds-faster-using-html5-web-audio-api), [тыц](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), [тыц](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Using_Web_Audio_API).

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего массив байт, находящийся в БД нужно от туда извлечь и поместить в ,PHP-массив. Для того, чтобы массив двоичных данных можно было передать на вебстраницу, нужно его закодировать в base64, после чего он отобразится в виде символов.
Дальше на странице то, что получилось, поместить в типизированный массив JavaScript, скажем, myArray, перед этим обратно раскодировав из base-64:

var myArray = new int8Array(window.btoa()); //тут вовнутрь внутренних скобок вставьте имя  php-переменной с массивом байт, т к тут он без форматирования не отображается.

new Audio(URL.createObjectURl(new Blob([myArray]))).play();

Упрощённо так. Но если есть возможность на c# отправить двоичные данные мп3-файла не в ту же таблицу, а в файл на сервере, то всё было б намного проще, останется только этот файл задать, как src для элемента аудио, и воспроизвести.